# .htaccess rules work in XAMPP but not on IIS 6

Tags: .htaccess, iis, xampp

I use `.htaccess` rewrite rules to redirect urls with the extension `.html` to `.php`.

These are my current rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ a/$1.php [NC]
```

How do I get these to work on IIS6?

Comment: Which version of IIS? IIS6 or IIS7/8?

Comment: Oh ya, i use iis v6, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache (which is the web server in XAMPP) `.htaccess` (mod_rewrite) rules won't work on IIS6. You need to install a third party rewriter such as [HeliconTech's ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) to achieve this.

IIS7+ supports rewriting out of the box but the format is different.

Comment: Ok i see know why its doesnt work, thank for the answer mr kev's :)